# Google Play store, Can no longer see Total Installs

Tags: android, google-play, playback

I have a few apps on the Google play store and use the number of total installs as part of my growth plan. 
However as of July 16, 2018 I can no longer see the "Total Installs" in my console. It only shows "Active Installs".

Did Google just remove one of the most important numbers from the play store?

How else can I get this stat? Can I get it in another screen or maybe through an API call?

Comment: Off topic, not programming related

Comment: @mast3rd3mon what if want to do this pro-grammatically ?

Answer (score 118):

As on 13 January 2020, you can still see total downloads.

1. Go to Statistics page in google play console.
2. Then go to Users -> User acquisitions -> New Users
   [image]
3. Select Metric calculation as cumulative
   [image]

Comment: That's it! I was missing the Cumulative parameter. Thanks!

Comment: "Cumulative" is not available for all metrics, like the "All users" user acquisitions, and may also be removed when you select "All period" for the time range

Comment: @HugoGresse Gresse All Users cumulative is not equal to total no of downloads as it includes returning users also. New users cumulative is the proper parameter to check the number of downloads. Also the number of downloads does show for  "All period"

Comment: Still valid on March 3, 2021.

Comment: Somebody mark this answer as "Answered" @Varol Okan

Comment: This works 2022-09-11

Answer (score 26):

Unfortunately, the "total user installs" metric was removed from the Statistics page in the Google Play Console a while back.

There is still a pretty simple way to get the total install count though (but it is admittedly a bit annoying). You can export a report that has your installs per month across the lifetime of your app, and sum all those together to get the total.

- Go to "Statistics" for your app from the Sidebar
- Make a new report where your metric from the first dropdown is "Installs by User"
- Change the interval to "Monthly", and set your date range to be "Lifetime"
- Export the report as a CSV, open it up in some spreadsheet software and do a sum for all of your downloads

I wrote a blog post about it [here](https://mnmapplications.com/2018/11/06/total-app-installs-count-play-console-2018/)

But I think a better way than that is to just write a tool which fetches all of your reports programatically from the Google Cloud Buckets so you can just click 1 button and generate any reports you might need. I talk about [how I built mine here](https://mnmapplications.com/2018/08/12/side-project-time-hacks-automating-android-app-performance-reports/) if you want to check it out.

Answer (score 17):

The [Android app for the Play Store console](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.playconsole) (still) shows the total install.

Select your app, press "VIEW DETAILS" in the "Installs by user" card, select "Lifetime" in the time span spinner.

Comment: Still true as of October 20th 2020, and only 13 days before US Election oO

Answer (score 15):

It seems like it is now possible again in some sort. In the dashboard of your app there is a section with the title *"How are your KPIs performing?"*.

In that section there is both a graph for *"New Users Acquired"* and *"Users lost"* (if that view mode is enabled) which also shows the total amount. The total amount is for the given period, but that can be changed above the sections - if set to "Lifetime" it shows the total users acquired and users lost.

Be aware that there is a difference between users acquired/lost and install/uninstall events. Highlight the questionmark next to the titles to get the definition of users acquired/lost.

I hope the image below shows what I mean. I unfortunaly had to hide the actual data, but hope it still makes sense.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

From the Google Play Console Android app, you can get this number pretty easly :

- Select your app
- Select the first card "User acquisitions"
- Chose "From when the app was launched"

And you can see the total here :

[image]

Answer (score 9):

As of April 2023 the Play Console has a built-in metric for this:

1. Click "Choose KPIs' in the Play Console Dashboard
   [image]
2. Under "Device growth and loss" there is a KPI called "Total installs" which tracks "The cumulative total number of times your app has been installed".
   [image]

Comment: This only shows total installs on active devices, rather than total downloads in total over time

Comment: @alfietap Nope. It tracks total installs to date. See the last option in the screenshot I posted.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is different from the metric which determines the ballpark shown in the public listing under downloads.

Answer (score 6):

Seems like it was removed from the main page for some reason but as of right now, you can still find out the total installs.

1. Open the dashboard in Play Console for your app, the first card you'll see is "Installs by user" which is what we need. Click "Explore report".

[image: Dashboard]

2. Click on date picker on the right and select "Lifetime".

[image: Date]

Now you should be able to see "Total installs by user" as well as some additional stats.

Comment: Can't find _"Total installs by user"_.

Answer (score 4):

After contacting google they said it was removed in order to restructure app store stats in general.

I am focused on user-growth and this is/was an important metric for me.

Today they messed up "Active installs". All my apps show 1

Google what are you doing ? 
I would recommend they do get user feedback before removing features ( Agile ) as well as test changes they push into production.

Answer (score 0):

I also observed that in Google Play Store only Active Installs are showing.

Comment: It's approximate. For example, I have an application with 4000 downloads and it says +1000 on the Playstore card.