# Google Play Developer Console total downloads statistic

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-console, developer-console

Google was changed Developer Console views. We can't reach total downloads in new view. Is there any way to find total download's? or would i add month by month? [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvxHM.png)

i choosed time interval to all of time

Comment: Same issue here... it looks like that information won't be available anymore...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51379013/google-play-store-can-no-longer-see-total-installs/59707264#59707264

Answer (score 0):

All of the updates to Play Console Data are described on [this help page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7003402). It looks like no recent change took total downloads away. So what you describe sounds like maybe a bug. You should contact Play Console support, which you can do via the help menu. This is on the "?" question mark icon.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found was set the period as lifetime and download csv file.

Then you can sum it easily with excel(window) or Numbers(mac).